# How Ruby GC count allocated RegularExpression

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

Today i learned about Ruby Garbage Collection, and do some test

```rb
def count_allocated_objects
  before = GC.stat(:total_allocated_objects)

  yield

  after = GC.stat(:total_allocated_objects)

  after - before
end

count_allocated_objects {
  s = "this is a string"
  r = /[a-z]/
} # => 1, so only the string `s` be counted

count_allocated_objects {
  s = "this is a string"
  s.gsub(/[a-z]/, "")
} # => 6, in this case, is the regex `/[a-z]/` counted ?
```

As you can see, it looks like the regex `/[a-z]/` is not counted by the `GC`.
is it the Ruby's rule or the GC's stat `total_allocated_objects` rule ?

Comment: I get `2` and `8` instead. So it's definitely something not stable and you can't rely on it per version/environments/etc.

Comment: I get `2` and `19` in Ruby 3.1

Answer (score 0):

Turn out the Regex is considered as `frozen object` (similar to the frozen String) and the `GC` will not count those `frozen objects`, so the Regex will not be counted. (regardless which Ruby version, at least so far)

```rb
count_allocated_objects {
  s1 = "this is a string"
  s2 = "another string"
  r = /[a-z]/
} # ruby 2.6.5 => 2, ruby 3.0.0 => 2, ruby 3.1.0 => 3
```

although `ruby 3.1.0` return 3, but if i remove `r` from the above code, it still return 3

```rb
count_allocated_objects {
  s1 = "this is a string"
  s2 = "another string"
} # ruby 2.6.5 => 2, ruby 3.0.0 => 2, ruby 3.1.0 => 3
```

test with a frozen String

```rb
count_allocated_objects {
  s1 = "this is a string"
  s2 = "another string".freeze
} # ruby 2.6.5 => 1, ruby 3.0.0 => 1, ruby 3.1.0 => 2
```

For sure i checked a frozen String and Regexp in `heap dump`

```rb
require 'objspace'
ObjectSpace.trace_object_allocations_start

s1 = "this is a string"
s2 = "another string".freeze
r = /[a-z]/

p r.frozen? # true
p ObjectSpace.dump(r) # "{..\"type\":\"REGEXP\", ... \"frozen\":true ...
p ObjectSpace.dump(s2) # "{..\"type\":\"STRING\", ... \"frozen\":true ...
p ObjectSpace.dump(s1) # didn't contain \"frozen\"
```